# How to build a long string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to build a long string the easiest way. I thought of use the `times` method, but using the following code it doesn't return that I am looking for:

```
10000.times{ "Foo bar" }
# => 10000
```

I would like that it returns `"Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar ..."`.

How can I make that?

*Note*: I would like to use the above code for testing purposes in a my rspec file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this method:

```
"Long string"*1000
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't work because you're calling the `times` method on the integer 1000. It's taking a block and ends up returning the value 1000.

The easiest solution is to call the multiplication method/operator on a string.

So like @gmile suggested do it like this:

```
"Foo bar " * 10000
```

But if you really want to use `10000.times{ }` you can do so like this:

```
long_string = ''
10000.times{ |s| s << 'Foo bar ' }
puts long_string   # "Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar ..."
```

Comment: ~gmile has the best solution, but better than this solution is 10000.times.inject('') { |str, ignore| str << 'Foo bar ' }